# App starts twice in oncreate

Tags: android

I am using the following code to obtain read write permissions, however the problem is, by having this piece of code in oncreate, my app starts twice instead of once. How do I fix this?

```
// **check if app has permission 1**//
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (!Settings.System.canWrite(this)) {
            requestPermissions(new String[] {
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE }, 2909);
        } else {
            // continue with your code
        }
    } else {
        // continue with your code
    }
```

here is rest of the code which is outside oncreate-

```
// **check if app has permission 2**//
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 2909: {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.e("Permission", "Granted");
        } else {
            Log.e("Permission", "Denied");
        }
        return;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can you tell that it starts twice?

Comment: because I have to exit it twice and It starts with a different animation (fade out instead of fade in)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to use this to check permission

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
```

this well return if permission is granted or revoked ...

refer to this tutorial [Requesting Permissions at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Answer (score -1):

for this particular example first you can check if permission is granted or not

```
checkSelfPermission( Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
```

if result is false then request permission

edit

change  `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)`
to

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && (checkSelfPermission( Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) || checkSelfPermission( Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)))
```

Comment: this makes it never request for permissions which defeats the whole purpose of this code

Comment: how is that? this checks if permission is not granted to ask. so if permission is granted you do not have to ask again.

Comment: dude I removed the permissions myself in settings and it never asked me again no matter if the permissions are granted or not